# Setting optional to nil causes crash - swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Ive declared an var coinObject: SCNNode? like so and created a coin object to fill this variable. If the coin goes off screen I remove it from the parent view and then attempt to make coinObject = nil so that I can create a new coin for coinObject. Problem is I get an error when attempting coinObject = nil.

```
        if coinObject != nil {

        coinObject!.removeFromParentNode()
        coinObject = nil }  // Crashes here
```

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Funny thing is Ive checked to make sure coinObject is not nil. Perhaps its some optional peculiarity I dont know about.

Comment: Are you sure it crashes on the setting to `nil` (not on the next time someone tries to use it)?

Comment: Definitely when setting nil first time around, if I comment it out the app doesn't crash.

Comment: That's a weak argument. If you don't set it to `nil` then no one will try to use it as `nil` and the app doesn't crash, either.

Comment: I don't understand why it's crashing when I set it to nil. I know there's an object in there but I want to remove it from memory because it's no longer retrievable on screen.

Comment: I also don't understand why it can crash when trying to set it to `nil`. That's why I thought maybe it crashes after that. But if it really does crash at that very line, that's an interesting situation. Can you provide more context (stack track and the like)?

Comment: I'll get back to you as im away from my laptop. Back later cheers

Comment: Check your assumptions. Where _exactly_ does the crash happen? At the assignment, or later? What happens when you step through the code?

Comment: I think Ive solved it with you guys help. (and yes it does crash right at that line of code) The question should be "do I actually need to assign nil to coinObject after it has had a coinObject before?" It appears I dont need to, I can just overwrite whats in there without setting it to nil prior. I guess I dont understand variables very well in Swift, I know in Python this is very easy to do. Still doesnt explain to me why I cant assign coinObject to nil even if there is something inside it already.